# How to loop over and access Vue data

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to loop over my code and grab the value of each form input because I want to display a total score and a severity score from my form inputs. The total score will calculate how many symptoms are present (0-3) and the severity score will calculate the severity of each symptom the user drags the slider to (0-18). I want each score to change as the user drags each slider.

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Headache</label>
  <input
    v-model="form2.headache"
    name = "headache"
    type="range" 
    min="0" max="6" 
    class="slider"><span v-text="form2.headache"></span>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <label class="label">"Pressure in head"</label>
  <input
    v-model="form2.pressureInHead"
    name = "pressureInHead"
    type="range" 
    min="0" max="6" 
    class="slider"><span v-text="form2.pressureInHead"></span>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <label class="label">Neck Pain</label>
  <input
    v-model="form2.neckPain"
    name = "neckPain"
    type="range" 
    min="0" max="6" 
    class="slider"><span v-text="form2.neckPain"></span>
</div>
<div class="field"> 
  <p>Total number of symptoms: {{ total }}</p>
  <p>Symptom Severity Score: {{ severity }}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
data: {
    form2: {  
      headache: 0, 
      pressureInHead: 0,
      neckPain: 0, 
  }
}
```

If the user dragged headache to 4, pressure in head to 0, and neck pain to 3, the total score would display 2 because 2 symptoms (headache and neck pain) are present and the severity score would display 7 (4+0+3).

I have tried writing computed functions, but I am not sure what to write in the for-loop. I can only find iterating over lists and arrays online. This is what I've tried writing to calculate the total:

```
computed: {
  total() {
    var totalScore = 0
    for(value in this.data.form2) {
      totalScore+=Number(value)
    }
    return totalScore
  },
}
```

Comment: The main problem with your loop is that `for..in` iterates the object **keys** so you'd want `Number(this.data.form2[value])`. As below, `Object.values()` is another option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want two computed functions, one for the total symptoms and another for the severity.

You can do your calculations using a *reduce* job. The first adds `1` for each symptom in `form2` over `0`. The second sums the values.

```js
computed: {
  totalSymptoms () {
    return Object.values(this.form2).reduce((sum, val) =>
        sum += (val > 0) ? 1 : 0, 0)
  },
  totalSeverity () {
    return Object.values(this.form2).reduce((sum, val) => sum += Number(val), 0)
  }
}
```

and use them in your template like

```html
<div class="field"> 
  <p>Total number of symptoms: {{ totalSymptoms }}</p>
  <p>Symptom Severity Score: {{ totalSeverity }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I just had to wrap the last val in the totalSeverity function you wrote in a number because I don't think each value is an integer type, but works perfectly fine now. Thanks a lot!